# C++. Случайные числа для инициализации приватной статической переменной.

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, static

Вопрос таков: есть такой класс (файл Network.h)

```
class Network
{
  static Nodes nodes;
  static Relations relations;
};
```

Мне требуется инициализировать сразу и nodes, и relations.
В файле Network.cpp я прописываю следующее:

```
Nodes Network::nodes = {
       Node(0),Node(1),
       Node(2),Node(3),
       Node(4),Node(5)
};
Relations Network::relations = 
{
       Relation(0,3, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(1,3, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(2,3, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(0,4, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(1,4, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(2,4, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(3,5, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(4,5, rand() % 10 - 5)
};
```

Проблема в том, что требуется прописать

```
 srand(time(nullptr))
```

Подскажите, где я должен это прописать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так не годится?

```
Relations Network::relations = 
{
       (srand(time(0)),Relation(0,3, rand() % 10 - 5)),
       Relation(1,3, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(2,3, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(0,4, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(1,4, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(2,4, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(3,5, rand() % 10 - 5),
       Relation(4,5, rand() % 10 - 5)
};
```

Но я не уверен, что это идеальное и переносимое решение. Хотелось бы от гуру стандартов услышать, точно ли инициализаторы вычисляются в порядке слева направо?

Еще вариант - в конструкторе `Relation` статический объект вспомогательного класса, в конструкторе которого вызывается `srand()`.

Comment: Ваш вариант кода не работает (неизвестные идентификаторы srand и time).

Comment: Кто ж вам доктор, что вы не подключили соответствующие заголовочные файлы? :) Вот упрощенная версия - https://ideone.com/lNua5F

Comment: Упс, моя ошибка. Прежде, чем задал вопрос, то пробовал разные варианты, но забывал их комментировать. И ошибку выдавало не в Network.cpp. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 3):

На вашем месте я бы использовал ленивую инициализацию:

```
class Network{
    static Relations& relations(){
        static Relations relations = {
           Relation(0,3, rand() % 10 - 5),
           //...
           Relation(4,5, rand() % 10 - 5)
        };

        return relations;
    }
};

int main(){
    srand(time(nullptr)) 
}
```

Локальная переменная `relations` проинициализируется при первом обращении к ней. Таким образом можно быть уверенным что функция `srand` будет вызвана раньше.

Comment: `Network::relations` можно вызвать и **до** `main`

Comment: @alexolut, там тоже следует использовать ленивую инициализацию :)